# QApplication dont exit after i close all QWidget

Tags: c++, qt5

I am programming a application that return a value with QWidget::exec, but seem that i cant close the class properly (i need call Gate::~Gate explicitly for delete the class) and QApplication::exec never exit.
Gate is the main window of my aplication

```
Gate::Gate(List *opciones, QWidget *parent):
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Gate)
{
    ParseOption *ctmp;
    int retvalue,i;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    validUser = false;
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose);
    errno = 0; // no se de donde sale el error...
    [...code...]
    QObject::connect(ui->closeButton,&QAbstractButton::clicked,this,&QDialog::close);
    QObject::connect(ui->passwordField,&QLineEdit::textChanged,this,&hellGate::enableopenButton);
    QObject::connect(ui->openButton,&QAbstractButton::clicked,this,&hellGate::certificateUser);
    QObject::connect(this,&hellGate::validateUser,this,&QDialog::done);
}
```

when mi program call:

```
emit validateUser(QDialog::Accepted);
```

then exit, but Gate when close dont call the destructor, i call this in main but with the flag WA_QuitonClose shall close automaticaly:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QWidgetList list;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Gate w(configOptions);
    if(w.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        w.~Gate();
        qDebug("enter");
    } else {
        qDebug("No enter");
    }
    list = a.topLevelWidgets();
    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
        for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++) {
            qDebug("window: %i",list[i]->close());
        }
    } else {
        qDebug("ALL closed");
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

the output is "enter" (and "ALL closed" if i call ~Gate).

i am trying that the program exit from the line "return a.exec()".
if i dont destruct Gate explicitly a.topLevelWidget return a list with the a QWidget(i suppose that is Gate).
i need call w.exec() because i need that Gate return a value and w.show() is declares as:

```
void show();
```

I need call w.exec and that a.exec finish when the windows w(class Gate) close.
 what am i doing wrong?

P.D Sorry if the text is difficult to understand, i dont know English very well.

Comment: Is Gate the main window of your application? Could you please clarify why you need to call its destructor explicitly? Usually you call show() of the main window and then exec() for app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create two event loops:

1. `w.exec()`
2. `a.exec()`

The second event loop is started **after** you close the dialog, so it will wait indefinitely for a window to be closed.

You can either call `show()` for the dialog or not use the QApplication event loop at all:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Gate w(configOptions);
    if(w.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        qDebug("enter");
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("No enter");
    }
}
```

Comment: i needed the QApplication because Gate inherit from QDialog

Comment: thne now i forcing the finish with a.quit, because i need w.exec for return a value

Comment: this respond why a.exec dont exit never, but no how i can do properly my program.

Comment: @JVM why do you need the `QApplication`? It should work without it.

Comment: the program throw:
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication  before a QWidget
if i quit QApplication

Comment: @JVM what did it throw?

Comment: the program throw this warning and crashed if i quit QApplication: 
    QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Comment: @JVM you are right, I edited the code. Just don't use `a.exec()` and it works

Comment: yes, but i need a.exec because the main window (w) must return Qt::Accepted, and w.show dont return a value

Comment: @JVM you need `w.exec()` instead of `a.exec()`! please see my code above, it works for me

Comment: Ok, now it work,  i am sorry, i dont know what happened, a lot of thanks for the help